# Facebook [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am geting function.file-get-contents failed to open when i try to connect with server , my server fails to connect ,same application work in all server but in my  server i am getting this error , Any solution , is that server CONFIG Issue ..

YOU CAN CHECK SERVER Config here http://gomandi.com/phpinfo.php

Answer (score 0):

In the last few days I saw a few complaints about file_get_contents not working well when trying to access facebook api using it.

Take a look at these threads:

- [Getting 404 Error from Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903240/getting-404-error-from-facebook-graph-api)
- [Facebook Auth with high traffic sites: empty access tokens, empty /me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333139/facebook-auth-with-high-traffic-sites-empty-access-tokens-empty-me)
- [Facebook API 400 Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324984/facebook-api-400-bad-request)

You might find out what's wrong there.  I suggest that you try to use something other than file_get_contents, such as curl, which was suggested in those threads as well (along side some code snippets)

Comment: Problem is i am not getting any error , app is only buffering  and token changing every second , you can check this at yuplee.in/fbapps/attract/

Comment: Can you show code? What do you mean by "app is only buffering"?

Comment: Our Server is Using session.use_cookies = 0 is this responsible for this problem.. App only buffering means ..App api keep on changing and fails to connect with my server.

Comment: You are using a lingo which is unknown to me. "App api keep changing"? What does that mean? And who fails to connect with your server? Anyway, if you want real help, you'll need to modify your original question and add the CODE to it.